# Converting response time format in Jmeter 5.4

Tags: jmeter

Is there any way , we can see response times in the listeners in Seconds in place of milliseconds in Jmeter 5.4 version.
I have tried changing in jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms property in jmeter.properties file, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6) it's not possible, you can divide the original response time by 1000 and overwrite the result.

If this is something you can live with it can be done using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following code:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.writeField(prev,'elapsedTime',(prev.getTime()/1000).longValue(),true)
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)